# How can I create an AWS Lambda function using the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I am trying to create an AWS Lambda function using the command

```
aws lambda create-function \
  --function-name foo\
  --runtime nodejs\
  --role lambda_basic_execution \
  --handler asdf --zip-file "fileb:://boom.zip"
```

I have a file called boom.zip available in the directory. But I cannot deploy using the above command.

The failure message I get is

> --zip-file must be a file with the fileb:// prefix.

Does anyone have a working example to create a lambda function using the AWS CLI?

Comment: In your snippet, you have "fileb:://" which is incorrect based on the error message.

Comment: I haven't got this working either. The example I'm working from has a longer `--role arn:aws:iam::$account_id:role/service-role/lambda_basic_execution` per https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/kotlin-and-groovy-jvm-languages-with-aws-lambda/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have an extra colon ':' in the file spec.

```
$ aws lambda create-function --function-name foo --runtime nodejs --role lambda_basic_execution --handler asdf --zip-file "fileb:://boom.zip"

--zip-file must be a file with the fileb:// prefix.
Example usage:  --zip-file fileb://path/to/file.zip

$ aws lambda create-function --function-name foo --runtime nodejs --role lambda_basic_execution --handler asdf --zip-file "fileb://boom.zip"

Error parsing parameter '--zip-file': Unable to load paramfile fileb://boom.zip: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'boom.zip'
```

Comment: Do we need to rename the .zip file name with the fileb::// prefix? Or is this just to be prepended while mentioning in the --zip-file option?

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje don't rename, it is not a valid file name. Just prepend it when using `--zip-file` option.

Comment: Thanks! Got this working, --zip-file took the Absolute path to the .zip file

Answer (score 5):

On mac I had to use absolute path, but added to the prefix there are actually 3 slashes.

Prefix:

```
fileb://
```

Path

```
/Users/myuser/Apps/folder/zips/file.zip
```

Complete

```
fileb:///Users/myuser/Apps/folder/zips/file.zip
```

Comment: aws should clarify that this `fileb://` is not an example of an s3 bucket.  if you're on mac, use `Complete` from this post ^ :pointup: ...  to get the full path use `pwd`.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 and what did the trick was enclosing both the name of the function and the `fileb:///` with double `"` quotes.

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name "FUNCTION" --zip-file "fileb:///an/absolute/path/to/your/lambda/FUNCTION.zip"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue occurred (in windows) because I didn't create the zip file correctly. I used the `winrar` tool to create the `.rar` file, changed the extension to `.zip`, and tried to upload the zip in the same way `@helloV` said (without double `::`), but I got the same error message. If you are in windows make sure to follow [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-package.html#golang-package-windows) guide (for golang), or use any other suitable tool to create a correct zip file and try the command out again.