# How to update aws lambda function using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I am unable to update my AWS Lambda function using the CLI command,
I created a .zip file and uploaded the .zip to the Lambda function via the AWS Console and it worked,
But the same file I am not able to upload using the AWS CLI,

**I am getting the following error while, trying to use the cli command -**

```
Error parsing parameter '--zip-file': Unable to load paramfile fileb:
```

**Command used to update the function -**

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name test --zip-file "fileb://$deployableName"
```

**File trying to upload -**
[image]

**I am referring the following links -**
1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html 
2. [AWS lambda update-function-code with jar package via AWS CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49611739/aws-lambda-update-function-code-with-jar-package-via-aws-cli)
3. [How can I create an AWS Lambda function using the AWS CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362805/how-can-i-create-an-aws-lambda-function-using-the-aws-cli)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this by specifying the `absolute path of the .zip file`,
to the --zip-file option.

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name test --zip-file "fileb:///home/user/poc/lambda/Monday-17-Jun-2019-1560756274.zip"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error

> Error parsing parameter '--zip-file': Unable to load paramfile fileb:

Indicates that the given file can not be found. Are you sure that:

- The variable is being correctly replaced by a value?
- The file exists? Check Relative/Absolute paths

Comment: Yes was able to upload the file - Monday-17-Jun-2019-1560756274.zip using console.

Comment: What I mean is, are you 100% sure $deployableName is replaced by Monday-17-Jun-2019-1560756274.zip?

Comment: When I echo $deployableName, it's displaying Monday-17-Jun-2019-1560756274.zip

Comment: But that still does not give any certainty it is replaced on that specific location. Try adding --debug and see if that output helps

Comment: ran the command using the --debug option, aws --debug lambda update-function-code --function-name test --zip-file "fileb://$deployableName", Shared O/P on question

Comment: Do I need to pass an absolute path of the .zip or something? The file is there, don't know whats going wrong.